# Running a constant number of goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm not completely sure what's going on here so it's hard to generalize my question, but I'm going to try my very best.

In a video from a few years ago Matt Parker dared his viewers to find a power of two, which does not contain any digits which are a power of two. (For example, 2^16 = 65536. None of these digits individually are a power of two). Recently I got into learning Go and I thought it would be a nice introductory exercise to get used to the language.

I created this pretty quickly and then I decided to try to make it concurrent to make full use of my quad core processor. This is where things went downhill.

The goal here is to run a constant amount of goroutines each of which processes a different batch of numbers. I implemented the program like so:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/big"
    "runtime"
)

//The maximum amount of goroutines
const routineAmt int = 3

//The amount of numbers for each routine to check
const rangeSize int64 = 5000

//The current start of the range to start checking
var rangeIndex int64 = 0

func main() {
    //loop forever
    for {
        //if we have less routines running than the maximum
        if runtime.NumGoroutine() < routineAmt {
            c := make(chan bool)
            // start a new one to check the next range:
            go checkRange(rangeIndex, rangeIndex+rangeSize, c)
            // wait for the signal that the values have been copied to the function, so that we can increment them safely:
            <-c
            close(c)
            // increment the rangeIndex for the next routine which will start:
            rangeIndex += rangeSize
        }
    }
}

// Function to check a range of powers of two, whether they contain any power-of-two-digits
func checkRange(from, to int64, c chan bool) {
    c <- true // signal to the main routine that the parameter values have been copied

    // Loop through the range for powers of two, which do not contain any power-of-two-digits
    for i := from; i < to; i++ {
        num := big.NewInt(2)
        num.Exp(num, big.NewInt(i), nil)
        if !hasStringPowerOfTwo(num.String()) {
            log.Println("Found 2 ^", i)
        }
    }
    log.Printf("Checked range %d-%d\n", from, to)
}

// Function to check if a string contains any number which is a power of two
func hasStringPowerOfTwo(input string) bool {
    powersOfTwo := [4]rune{'1', '2', '4', '8'}
    for _, char := range input {
        if runeInArray(char, powersOfTwo) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

// Function to check if a list of runes contains a certain rune
func runeInArray(a rune, list [4]rune) bool {
    for _, b := range list {
        if b == a {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

After waiting about 15 minutes or so, the program still did not finish a single go routine (that is, I did not see `log.Printf("Checked range %d-%d\n", from, to)` in the console)

I tried lowering the range size to 5, which resulted in a few goroutines to be completed but it abruptly stopped at the range 2840-2845. I thought this might be due to the numbers getting bigger and the calculation taking more time, but this doesn't make sense as the stop is very abrupt. If this were the case I would expect the slowdown to be at least a little gradual.

Comment: If you issue a SIGQUIT to a running Go program, it will issue stack traces for all running goroutines, which might be helpful. When it seems to have slowed excessively, send a SIGQUIT and see what it's up to.

Comment: Don't use `runtime.NumGoroutine` in your program logic. Either start a known number of goroutines, or dispatch them as needed. There are dozens of resources on concurrency patterns to choose from.

Comment: Try using a WaitGroup https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_WaitGroup

Comment: you can also use a [semaphore] (https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/semaphore) to limit the number of goroutines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using a for loop with a check on `runtime.NumGoroutine` to make sure you don't have too many routines running, because the loop will prevent the goruntime to schedule your routines properly, it will slowdown the whole thing.

Instead, you should use a buffered channel which signals when a routine is done, so that you can start a new one.

I have adjusted your `main` function and `checkRange` function:

```golang
func main() {
        var done = make(chan struct{}, routineAmt)
        //loop forever
        for i := 0; i < routineAmt; i++ {
                // start a new one to check the next range:
                go checkRange(done, rangeIndex, rangeIndex+rangeSize)
                // increment the rangeIndex for the next routine which will start:
                rangeIndex += rangeSize
        }

        for range done {
                // start a new one to check the next range:
                go checkRange(done, rangeIndex, rangeIndex+rangeSize)
                // increment the rangeIndex for the next routine which will start:
                rangeIndex += rangeSize
        }
}

// Function to check a range of powers of two, whether they contain any power-of-two-digits
func checkRange(done chan<- struct{}, from, to int64) {
        // Loop through the range for powers of two, which do not contain any power-of-two-digits
        for i := from; i < to; i++ {
                num := big.NewInt(2)
                num.Exp(num, big.NewInt(i), nil)
                if !hasStringPowerOfTwo(num.String()) {
                        log.Println("Found 2 ^", i)
                }
        }
        log.Printf("Checked range %d-%d\n", from, to)

        // let our main go routine know we're done with this one
        done <- struct{}{}
}
```